# I get NULL when I want to grab a string in activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a String from one activity to another and it returns NULL, the string in question has the uri of an image that I saved previously.

in the activity one I have a function that saves the image and puts the string URI in a variable of the class. Next I put the code.

Activity One

```
public class PaintActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaintView {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paint);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    intent = new Intent(this, ResultsActivity.class);

    readyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                paintImage.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = paintImage.getDrawingCache();

                saveImage(bitmap);

                presenter.getColorList();
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Tersuave");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();

    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        // sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        //     Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    image_path = uri.toString();
                    intent.putExtra("image_path", image_path);
                }
            });

}
```

}

Then in onCreate method

```
paintImage.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = paintImage.getDrawingCache();

// this method is the one above 
saveImage(bitmap);
presenter.getColorList();
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity Two

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

// return null
String image = intent.getStringExtra("image_path");
```

Comment: Try to run the `startActivity(intent);` inside the onScanCompleted. You switch Activities before the scan is completed.

Comment: Can you show your complete code? It's hard to follow what's going on here. But it looks like you immediately start Activity Two inside the `onCreate()` function of Activity One. However, `image_path` won't be set until that OnScanCompletedListener is invoked, which will almost always happen after `startActivity()` is called.

Comment: There add the code of activity one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you persist the image file after scanner result you could do something like this to start next activity.

```
     MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                image_path = uri.toString();

               Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity2.class);
               intent.putExtra("image_path", image_path);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And inside Activity2 you could do something like this.

```
    String imageFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_path");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your implementation you are triggering activity ResultsActivity before and adding the value image_path in to extra into the call back which is delayed.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                image_path = uri.toString();
                intent.putExtra("image_path", image_path); // this will be called after some time

            }
        });


presenter.getColorList();
startActivity(intent);
```

Add above two line after intent.putExtra inside the OnScanCompletedListener and remove it form onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity you should do this if yo want to pass the string in the intent

FirstActivity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("Keyname", image_path);
 startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity

onCreate....

```
if(savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras == null)
                {
                    //Extra bundle is null
                }else{
                    String image = extras.getString("Keyname");
                }
```